# CIFilter + UIImage + alpha mask

Tags: ios, objective-c, mask, cifilter

I'm using such solution to mask my `UIImage` with some alpha drawing:
[masking an UIImage](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/how-to-mask-an-image.html#comment-47347)

The problem is that later i want to apply some `CIFilters`. However when i change value of the filter, my alpha gets lost from `UIImage`. Do i have to re-apply the alpha channel to output image each time after modifying CIFilter? This will surely make the process much slower.

Samples of code: (each new paragraph is in another method)

```
// set the image
_image = [incomeImage imageWithMask:_mask]; // imageWithMask from method from link
[_myView.imageView setImage:_image];

// calculate ciimages
_inputCIImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:_image.CGImage options:nil];
_myView.imageView.image = _image;
_currentCIImage = _inputCIImage;

// change value in filter
[filter setValue:@(0.2f) forKey:@"someKey"];
[filter setValue:_inputCIImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
_currentCIImage = [filter outputImage];
CGImageRef img = [_context createCGImage:_currentCIImage fromRect:[_currentCIImage extent]];
UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:img];
```

Comment: It shouldn't have to get lost technically. Show us the code?

Comment: @Nikhita Added most important parts of code.

Comment: you could do this only using CIFilters. Instead of using imageWithMask you can use the `CIBlendWithMask` CIFilter.

Comment: By "you could do this only using CIFilters" you mean that it's natural behaviour of CIFilter to remove alpha channel? I'll try CIBlendWithMask then.

Comment: @JonathanCichon Could you please post your comment as an answer? I will accept it because it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could do this only using CIFilters. Instead of using `imageWithMask` you can use the `CIBlendWithMask` CIFilter. [Apple CIFilter Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIBlendWithMask)