# CIBlendWithMask sizes

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cgcontext, cifilter

I'm trying to create an image with mask using filter. I have 3 images, all of them with same size:

```
(lldb) p img1.size
(CGSize) $33 = (width=369, height=370)
(lldb) p img2.size
(CGSize) $34 = (width=369, height=370)
(lldb) p img3.size
(CGSize) $36 = (width=369, height=370)
```

Then i'm allocating CIImages for them:

```
CIImage *inputImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:img1.CGImage options:nil];
CIImage *bgImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:img2.CGImage options:nil];
CIImage *maskImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:img3.CGImage options:nil];
```

And create CIFilter with given CIImages:

```
CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIBlendWithMask"];
[filter setValue:inputImage forKey:@"inputImage"];
[filter setValue:bgImage forKey:@"inputBackgroundImage"];
[filter setValue:maskImage forKey:@"inputMaskImage"];
CIImage *outputImage = [filter outputImage];
```

However, when i'm trying to get outputImage like this:

```
CGImageRef outputRef = [_context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:[outputImage extent]];
UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:outputRef];
CGImageRelease(outputRef);
```

Result image has strange size:

```
(lldb) p outputImage.size
(CGSize) $37 = (width=738, height=740)
```

When i take a look into the image, it is located on bottom left (CGContext inverted Y-ax) and has a size of these 3 initial images (width=369, height=370), rest of image size is just empty (alpha = 0.0f). Mask is applied on full area, what is ok.

It may be important, that in the beginning i do something like this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(img2.size, NO, 0.0);
UIImage *img1 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); // transparent image
[anotherImg drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,img2.size.width,img2.size.height)];
UIImage *img3 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); // mask image with proper size
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

When I use in filter anotherImage instead of img3 as mask, output image is with correct size (img2 is drawn on full area instead of 1/3) however the mask is smaller (1/3 of size while it should be full area). So opposite situation.

What am I doing wrong? How to fix it, so i have both image and mask drawn on full area?
As a note - i have to use filter, [cant draw with mask in cgcontext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273724/cifilter-uiimage-alpha-mask?rq=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot about scaling to retina. This should help:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(img2.size, NO, img2.scale);
```